# Form validation is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter. I have created one function to add university form.

```
function add_uni_admin()
{
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
    if (!empty($user_id)) {             
            $uni_name = $this->input->post("uni_name");
            $uni_image = $this->input->post("uni_image");
            $uni_email = $this->input->post("uni_email");
            $phn_no = $this->input->post("phn_no");
            $m_no = $this->input->post("m_no");
            $address = $this->input->post("address");
            $password = $this->input->post("pass");

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('uni_name', 'University Name', 'required');               
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('uni_email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phn_no', 'Phone Number', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('m_no', 'Mobile Number', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required|matches[conf_pass]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_pass', 'Confirm Password', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
                $this->load->view("admin/add_uni_admin");                       
            } else {
                echo "successfull";exit;
            }           
    } else {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

When I submit the form without filling any field then it does not give any error.Here I have added **form_validation** library into **autoload.php** file and added **form** helper in it.

So what code should I have to write to display errors?

Comment: use `echo validation_errors()` in your view file (admin/add_uni_admin.php) to display error

Comment: If the validation is not running, have you tried loading the form validation in the controller just to see if the auto loading is failing?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I have written that in my view page.

Comment: @gabe3886  I have added form_validation in autoload.php page.

Comment: @Nisarg In the controller before you set your validation, add the code `$this->load->library('form_validation');` to see if the problem is with the auto loading of the library, or if there's a problem with the rules being set

Comment: first check you are getting value of $user_id. if so Then check like this 
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
print_r($this->form_validation);exit;
}

Comment: Is this CodeIgniter 3 or 2.x?

Comment: @Narf its Codeigniter 2.x..

Comment: @user1048123 I have checked it. $user_id and form_validation both are giving output.

Comment: @Nisarg CI 2.x ignores empty forms. More specifically, the form validation won't run if `$_POST` is empty.

Comment: @Nisarg so form_validation is giving error. check error form more detail or print_r(validation_errors()) in place of print_r($this->form_validation)

Comment: @user1048123 i have written **print_r($this->form_validation)**. So it gives array and in this array it shows error. And in my view page i have written  **echo validation_errors()** but error is not display. What is missing?

Comment: Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen. However it will show warning like this in console. So it is affect on it ?

Comment: @Nisarg in view try form_error('fieldname'). and check it will show error or not

Answer (score 0):

use `echo validation_errors()` in your view to display errors.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

**your form here.**

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `$this->load->library('form_validation');`
in your controller function..

And `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>`
in your view file to display errors.